# Select a link in a table row based on cell content

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

Using Selenium IDE, I am trying to locate a link within a table row. The table rows are dynamically generated. Each row has some cell with text content and a cell with possibly two or more links.

What I'd like to do is to create an automated test that clicks a specific link within a specific row as referenced by a specific text. For example, on the table below:

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
 <tr>
   <td>
    Hello World!
   </td>
   <td>
    Type Greeting
   </td>
   <td>
    <a href="www.foo.com/view/id=123456">View</a>
    <a href="www.foo.com/delete/id=123456">Delete</a>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>
    Buenos Dias!
   </td>
   <td>
    Type Greeting 
   </td>
   <td>
    <a href="www.foo.com/view/id=789101">View</a>
    <a href="www.foo.com/delete/id=789101">Delete</a>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The scenario is, on a previous page I add data "Buenos Dias!". The next page will display a table of all data added. I want to be able to click on the "View" link of the data that was just added (in this case, the "Buenos Dias!" entry).

What would be a good way to locate the "View" link by referencing the text "Buenos Dias!"?

I am able to locate the cell which contains the text:

```
//td[text()="Buenos Dias!"]
```

But I want to use it somehow as a reference for locating its respective "View" link from the table. I tried out sibling formats (following, preceding) and I cant seem to get it to work right. Using an absolute xpath (html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a[1]) will not work as the data could change and the entry appear on a different row.

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need more information.

- Selenium IDE 1.7.2
- Firefox 9.0.1
- Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use**:

```
(//td[normalize-space() ="Buenos Dias!"])[1]/following-sibling::td[2]/a[. = 'View']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//find table first
 WebElement q=  d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='applicationcontent']/div[6]/table/tbody/tr"));

// find a unique value of the row and click on link of the row which is after the text you find.
         q.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'abcd@gmail.com')]/following-sibling::td/a[@id='edit.png']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

(//td[normalize-space() ="Buenos Dias!"])[1]/following-sibling::td[2]/a[. = 'View']